# Обновление блока

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Как сделать блок который обновляеться каждые N секунд. Этот блок емеет include "content.dat" если я что нибудь изменяю в content.dat то на странице изменяеться этот блок без обновленияы

Answer (score 1):

Технология называется commet

**Есть несколько способов:**

1. *Длинные опросы (longpoll):* страница создает запрос к серверу, сервер оставляет этот запрос висеть пока данные не изменяться. Как только данные изменились, посылается ответ на запрос с новыми данными, клиент их обновляет.

[image: longpoll]
*Источник: learn.javascript.ru*

2. *Короткие опросы:* клиентская часть отправляет запросы по таймеру, если данные поменялись, рендерит их.
3. *Веб сокеты (WebSocket):* отдельный протокол над http для двусторонней связи клиента и сервера.

Подробнее и про другие способы вы можете прочитать здесь:
https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax
https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-longpoll
https://learn.javascript.ru/websockets

Answer (score 0):

Подключите в head JQuery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Затем создаете блок, где будет отображаться информация, либо берете уже существующий

```
<div id = "updateblock">
Загрузка информации, пару секунд...
</div>
```

И затем вставляете скрипт:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function runMultiple()
    {
         $.ajax({
          url: 'content.dat', // ваш файл
          success: function(data) {
              $("#updateblock").html(data); // блок, который обновляем
          }
        });
    }
    var timerMulti = window.setInterval("runMultiple();", 2000); // 2000 миллисекунд
    </script>
```

Comment: возможно, появилась уже новая версия JQuery, т.к. код взял со своего старого проекта, но на работоспособность это не повлияет

Comment: Код рабочий, но у меня в том файле (content.dat) есть много include'ов  и они не отображаються что делать???

Comment: если вы о include'ах на php, то очевидно, что расширение файла должно быть .php, а не .dat

Comment: include это php код, посудите логично на странице php (index.php) есть инклуд тоесть этот инклуд сокращение размера самой странице его можно заменить тем же кодом поэтому в каком формате файла разницы нет